# i want to copy contents of one file to another file and wherever i encounter word "USER" replace it with "Hello"

Tags: java

sample.txt

FLTR  TID: 0000007899    RPC ID: 0000137687  Queue: List      Client-RPC: 390620
**USER: taranveer.vij@unisys.com**    Overlay-Group: 1

I need something like this

tempFile.log

FLTR   TID: 0000007899   RPC ID: 0000137687   Queue: List    Client-RPC: 390620
**USER: 3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg**      Overlay-Group: 1

i tried this but i am not able to make it

```
private static void CreateTempFile() throws IOException
{

       BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new   FileReader("D:\\AdhocTask_ClientLog005.log"));
       PrintStream out=new PrintStream("D:\\tempFile.log");
       String readline=null;

       while((readline=buff.readLine())!=null)
       {
           if(readline.contains("FLTR"))
           {
                String how=(String) ((String) readline.subSequence(97,142)); //this gives taranveer.vij@in.unisys.com
                String word=how.replace(how,"3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg");
                out.println(word);
            }else{
                out.println(readline);
            }
        }
        out3.close();
        buff.close();
}
```

but in this program only  "3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg" printing in place whole line.I want full line but replace only USER filed.. something like this

FLTR   TID: 0000007899   RPC ID: 0000137687   Queue: List    Client-RPC: 390620
**USER: 3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg**      Overlay-Group: 1

Comment: I think your code has some errors... anyway the problem with the whole line I think is there: String word=how.replace(how,"3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg"); try with instead: String word=readline.replace(how,"3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg");

Comment: @albciff...+1 for you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the whole line is there:

`String word=how.replace(how,"3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg");`

try with instead:

`String word=readline.replace(how,"3@#$@fghfkjCNBMFS!@fg");`

Hope this helps,