# I want to Decrypt particular string in a text file and write it to another file

Tags: java, string, encryption

**sample.log** contains

```
FLTR  TID: 0000003756   RPC ID: 0000108159   Queue: Admin   Client-RPC: 390626         USER: **[B@4783165b**   Overlay-Group: 1
```

I need it to be like this

```
FLTR  TID: 0000003756   RPC ID: 0000108159   Queue: Admin   Client-RPC: 390626         USER: "DECRYPTED VALUE"   Overlay-Group: 1
```

Use secret key as

```
String key = "ThisIsASecretKey";
```

This is what i have tried please edit wherever i wrote wrong code..

```
public class Decrypt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.log"));
        String newStr = null;
        String value = "";
        while ((newStr = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String next = null;
            if (newStr.contains("FLTR")) {
                next = newStr.substring(97, 135); // this gets string **[B@4783165b**
                String collect = CallToDecrypt(next, value);
                system.out.println(collect);
            }
        }
        pt.close();
        br.close();
    }

    private static String CallToDecrypt(String next, String value) {
        String key = "ThisIsASecretKey";
        byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        if (raw.length != 16) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
        }
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal();
        return new String(original, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    }
}
```

Thanks to each one of you

Comment: Indent your code with four spaces to mark it as code. Then add proper indentation to your functions.

Comment: @CodesInChaos.... whats wrong in my code so that i am not getting decrypted values???

Comment: Sorry, but there are about 50 things that can be wrong with encryption/decryption.  To begin with the data may not even be encrypted correctly or may have been corrupted in handling.  (The value you're decoding is the result of doing `toString` on a non-stringish object.)

Comment: Please fix [the first post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949349/i-want-to-copy-contents-of-one-file-to-another-file-but-while-copying-i-should-r) instead of posting the same question [again and again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990589/i-want-to-copy-contents-of-one-file-to-another-file-and-wherever-i-encounter-wor).

Comment: @OlegEstekhin.... i fixed first post and now trying to decrypt but some where its missing....

Answer (score 0):

You are tying to decrypt nothing right now: the String `next` is never used in the `CallToDecrypt` routine.

You will have to do something like

```
byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(next.getBytes());
```

Comment: @DawnKeeper...i am getting exception like  ...Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
 at com.unisys.Decrypt.DecryptFunction(Decrypt.java:61)
 at com.unisys.Decrypt.main(Decrypt.java:44)

Comment: @Madiwalappa - Study up on encryption.  It's quite common for an algorithm to require a fixed-size block of data, meaning you may have to pad the last block being processed.